# Python Progressbar mouse click to seek

Tags: python-2.7, events, progress-bar, width

Win-7, Python 2.7.

I am making an app that handles a  music player, and uses a progress bar to show the current position of the playing song.

I would like to click the progress bar to seek to a position within the song.

The progress bar changes size as the user changes the width of the parent window.

I can get the x,y mouse coord within the progress bar OK, but getting the width is proving a bit more difficult.
Is there a way I can determine the current width of the progress bar?

I have tried event.winfo_width() and others, but keep getting "AttributeError: Event instance has no attribute 'winfo_width'"

```
def PositionIt(event):
    print
    print "Progress x=" + str(event.x) + "  y=" + str(event.y)
    print event.winfo_width()
# other methods I have tried
#   print event.winfo_screenwidth()
#   print event.winfo_geometry()

def SetupProgressBar(f_p, row, col):
    s = ttk.Style()
    s.theme_use('winnative')
    s.configure("TProgressbar", thickness=12)
    globs.currently_playing_progress_elapsed = 10

    p_bar = ttk.Progressbar(f_p, 
            style="TProgressbar", 
            orient="horizontal", 
            mode='determinate', 
            length=0,
            variable = globs.currently_playing_progress_elapsed)
    p_bar.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=('ew'))
    p_bar.columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
    p_bar.maximum = 100
    p_bar.bind("<Button-1>", PositionIt)
```

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my bad,

```
print event.winfo_width()
```

should read:

```
print event.widget.winfo_width()
```

Mark.